# How to see what softwares of my computer send to network?

Tags: networking

I need a software or a method to see all of data which is being sent to any outter network specially internet (data packets,Binary strings and formatted data like xml files) from my computer by a web based software or other applications.
to collect all of mentioned advantages in a single software is hard but i stress on formatted data ,desktop softwares and internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case You can also use "nbtstat -v -b" on windows which displays tcp sessions with remote tcp socket including the file responsible on localhost for tcp session.Wireshark have very good packet filtering capabilities on per protocol basis ; you can find it on wiki.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) software which is a very powerfull free software for your need

Answer (score 0):

you can find a nice example here http://gforgeek.blogspot.com/2005/04/simple-packet-sniffer-using-java.html .

You can use it by utilizing jpcap.jar from winpicap ( http://winpcap.polito.it/ )